# Combine / overlay different types of graphs with "lattice" and "latticeExtra"

Tags: r, data-visualization, bar-chart, lattice

I'm trying to combine or that is to say overlay a barchart with a xyplot (with regression line) with two variables whose values are quite different.

Here's my data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aacbkmo577uagjs/example.csv

There are the two numeric variables "rb" and "rae" and several factor variables (sample.size, effect.size, allocation.design, true.dose) that are to be displayed in panels according to the code below. The variable "rae" should be displayed in a barchart (ideally in faint colors in the background), whereas the variable "rb" is to be displayed in a xyplot with a regression line. There are two main questions:

(1) How to combine / overlay both types of graphs?
(2) How to customize axes labels (different scales for y-scale)

For (1), I know how to combine different types of graphs with ggplot2, but it should be also possible with lattice, am I right? I tried "doubleYScale", which doesn't seem to work.

For (2), I only accomplished to use "relation='free'" for the y-scale in the "scales"-option (see code). This is nice since the focus is on the important range of the values. However, it would be more appropriate if axes-labels are additionally drawn on the left and right outside (for "rae" and "rb", respectively).

Here's the code so far (modified by Dieter Menne to be self-contained)

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
df.dose <- read.table("example.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
df.dose <- transform(df.dose, 
                    sample.size=as.factor(sample.size),
                    true.dose = as.factor(true.dose))

rae.plot <- xyplot(
  rae ~ sample.size | allocation.design*true.dose,                
  df.dose, as.table=TRUE, 
  groups = type, 
  lty = 1, jitter.x=TRUE, 
  main="RAE", 
  scales=list(y=list(draw=F, relation="free", tck=.5)), 
  panel = function(x,y) { 
    panel.xyplot(x,y,jitter.x=TRUE)
    panel.lmline(x,y, col="darkgrey", lwd=1.5) 
  })

useOuterStrips(rae.plot)

rb.plot <- barchart(
  rb ~ sample.size | allocation.design*as.factor(true.dose), 
  df.dose, as.table=TRUE, 
  groups = type, 
  key=list(
    text=list(levels(as.factor(df.dose$type))), 
    scales=list(y=list(draw=F, relation="free", tck=.5)), 
    main="RB"))

useOuterStrips(rb.plot)
```

Comment: Please check you code if it is really self-contained in a new window; it is nice that you provided the data, but "punkt" was undefined, so I removed it. It is a better ideas to provide the data by dput, or, as your case is simple, by a simulation; or make sure that you dropbox is not erased for the next decade.

Comment: Dear Dieter, sorry for the inconvenient way to provide the data. Thank you for both the advice and for the corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(useOuterStrips(rae.plot), split=c(1,1,1,2),more=TRUE)
print(useOuterStrips(rb.plot), split=c(1,2,1,2), more=FALSE)
```

will print both on one page; it's easier than in ggplot2.

```
scales=list(
  y=list(alternating=1,tck=c(1,0)),
  x=list(alternating=1,tck=c(1,0)))
xyplot (... scales=scales)
```

Comment: Dear Dieter, thanks for the hint with "split"; in order to achieve overlayed plots, "split=c(1,1,1,1)" is required for both print-lines.

Comment: With reference to (2), I'd like to have a axis scale on the left side for "rae" and on the right side for "rb", since both values are quite different. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: but how do I anyway place the y-axis ticks and labels on the right margin? The "scales"-option doesn't have something like "side" or "position".